# Multidimensional array and Array of structure in OpenMP

Tags: c++, arrays, structure, openmp

I was using an array of structure in OpenMP but it was failing instead I used multi-dimensional array it gave me proper result. I wonder why.
Definition of structure used:

```
struct loc (  

float **mig;  

}  

loc *Loc = new loc[nthread];  
for(i=0; i<nthread; i++)  
{  
    Loc[i].mig = new float*[nx];  
    for(j=0; j<nx; j++)  
    {  
         Loc[i].mig = new float[ny];  
    }    
}
```

Loc is shared in parallel section and accessed using tid.
This implementation failed.

Than I used multi-dimentional array:

```
float ***mig;
mig = new float**[nthread];  
for(i=0; i<nthread; i++)  
{  
     mig[i] = new float*[nx];  
     for(j=0; j<nx; j++)  
     {  
          mig[i][j] = new float[ny];  
     }  
 }
```

mig is shared in parallel section. This implementation worked. Here 2D mig is accessed using tid as first dimension.

In both cases mig array is populated in parallel for clause.

First case fails giving segmentation fault but second case is executing successfully giving correct output.

As mig has to be assigned value from a native C code so vector is not used.

Kindly help me to understand the difference between two.

Comment: Y U NO USE `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` ???

Comment: You can't be serious about this `float ***mig;`??? Typical newbie pointer abuse that is completely unnecessary and unwarranted. STAHP. Just go and learn proper C++.

Comment: The first version should contain `loc *Loc = new loc[nthread];`

Comment: Just a hint for when asking future questions on Stack Overflow - most times it is not enough to show how an entity is declared and initialised, but also how it is used. And to also describe what you mean by "it fails". Error messages and compiler output are welcome.

Comment: first version is loc *Loc = new loc[nthread]; it was typo mistake here.

Comment: As mig has to be assigned value through native C code so didn't used vector

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be...

```c
for(i=0; i<nthread; i++)
{
    Loc[i].mig = new float*[nx];
    for(j=0; j<nx; j++)
    {
        Loc[i].mig = new float[ny];
        //        ^------------------------ right here
    }
}
```

You have a typo in the innermost loop. You should write this instead:

```
for(j=0; j<nx; j++)
{
    Loc[i].mig[j] = new float[ny];
}
```

Shouldn't C++ warn of implicit conversion from `float *` to `float **`?